# Blazor Slider Range Input vs Button - different on mobile Android browsers vs Browser

Tags: c#, android, blazor

So the below code updates the slider description from CheckSliderRating() on PC browsers (including chromium), but after publishing the slider will only update the text on an Android browser if I click the Save button. Is there anyway to make the slider work on its own (calling Save() from CheckSliderRating() doesn't work) ?

Razor Page/Component:

```
@using BlazorWithIdentity.Shared
@page "/Updrs"

<div class="unit">
    <div class="label">How do you rate Blazor?</div>
    <div class="labelTarget">
        <input type="range"
               step="1"
               min="1"
               max="5"
               @bind-value="@rating"
               @onclick="@CheckSliderRating" />
        <div id="slidertext" class="label"> @sliderText  </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <button type="submit" @onclick="@Save">Submit</button>
</div>

@code {
    SliderRatingText ratingtext;

    int rating { get; set; }

    string sliderText { get; set; }

    protected void CheckSliderRating()
    {
        if (ratingtext == null)
            ratingtext = new SliderRatingText();

        sliderText = ratingtext.CheckRating(rating);
    }

    protected void Save()
    {
        if (ratingtext == null)
            ratingtext = new SliderRatingText();

        sliderText = ratingtext.CheckRating(rating);

        sliderText = sliderText + " ";
  }
}
```

Class:

```
public class SliderRatingText
{

public string CheckRating(int rating)
        {
            switch (rating)
            {
                case 1:
                    sliderText = "Very slow";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    sliderText = "Not too slow - fast development";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    ;
                    sliderText = "Great for small Apps";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    sliderText = "Amazingly fast development";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    sliderText = "Amazing -Steve Sanderson should be knighted";
                    break;
            }
           return sliderText;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end adding

```
 @bind-value:event="oninput"
 @onchange="CheckSliderRating"
```

resolved the issue.